# Workflow with a List with more than 5000 items

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, internal-server-error

For some weeks I have been working with a Workflows and SharePoint Designer and SharePoint Online.

So, the Task List has more than 5 000 elements. Then, the workflow stop every time it execute this action:

Set Variable_1 in Association: Task List:Column

I guess its because it is getting the value using GUID from the Assign task.

[image]

So, is there any way or recommendation from Microsoft to resolve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Can create Indexing on GUID column? Manually start list indexing and try again after sometime (You can turn on indexing only if number of items are less than 5K). Please let me know if it helps

Comment: Hi, Rohit is not possible to add index to GUID with SharePoint using the browser.